# Long bus powered device protection

Tags: protection, esd

I'm looking to have several devices attached to a long (total ~10 m) powered i2c bus. The bus would be regulated to 5V at one end and the whole system will operate in exposed outdoor conditions on a balcony (i.e. limited protection from weather exposure and humans/squirrels poking it occasionally). Each individual device on the bus will contain an MCU and a suite of sensors.

This question is specifically about protecting the device ports (power/signal) on the bus from over voltage. Other concerns such as mechanical protection, coating, UV resistance, thermal dissipation in hot summers are out of scope.

I have a reverse polarity protection on the input to each device using a p-ch mosfet (it has already prevented me from frying a couple of micros during testing and development...) but I'm wondering if I should add additional protection on the power/signal lines in the form of a TVS and/or zener. I'm thinking about coupling from nearby lightning strikes/weather/mains and ESD from curious humans and "wildlife" on the balcony (is that a thing?).

Are such protections a reasonable thing to add or am I overestimating the possible damage?

Comment: Depending on the length and arrangement, it is possible to pickup tens of thousands of volts just by being outside in the right weather conditions... see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-_MsOjQEC3k) by Mr. Carlson.

Comment: Protection against squirrels? You are optimistic.

Comment: @rdtsc interesting, so I'm not crazy...

Comment: @BrianDrummond like I said, mechanical protection is another topic.